# how to fix height for two div's inside a mail div

Tags: html, css

page: http://jsbin.com/eniva4/edit

I have one main div: `#main-content` which contains two div's : `#announcement` and `.tabbed_content`

I want both the two divs to have same height, meaning their background color should end at the same height.

Right now notice that  `#announcement` seems to have more height than `.tabbed_content`

I can hardcode the height pixels value but I want to know if there is a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equal height columns are a common problem in site layout.  Here's an article that mentions a few solutions:

http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61

And one more:

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Answer (score 0):

`html,body{height:100%;}` an browser height wrapping issue http://jsbin.com/eniva4/2/edit